# Creating a Divided Map Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am creating a game in SpriteKit using Swift. The game requires the player to be able to select a certain state in the Unites States using a map like this.
[image]

Is there a program  or technique I could use in order to draw the outlines of the states, and turn each state into is own unique node within the map? For example, I would like to be able to tap the Illinois node, and then have my app recognize that I have tapped Illinois. I have no idea where to start and understand that this is not an easy task. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can use photoshop or gimp's magic wand and create the 50 textures you need.  Then put them together via code

Comment: It is an fairly easy task. You may even do this in scene editor and put sprites together visually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach I can think of is creating several images (one for each state) and finally adding them to your scene (each one at its own correct position).

Having a separate sprite for each state will make easier several operations like

- detecting which state has been tapped
- chaining the color of a state
- zoom a state
- apply a texture to a state

### Cutting the images

Starting from the input image you posted in your question you could use a Image Editing Tool (like [Pixelmator](https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/pixelmator/id407963104?l=en&mt=12)) with [mask functionality](http://www.pixelmator.com/tutorials/selections/quick-mask-mode/) to extract the images for each state.

### Positioning the Sprites

The same image editor, after you separated the images will probably provide you with the position of that state inside the canvas. You'll need to use these to reposition the state inside the canvas. Or you could youse the Xcode SpriteKit Scene editor to manually positions the images.

Comment: And what you think about tapping part? I guess that creating body from a texture would be ideal here?

Comment: @Whirlwind: Yes I would create a `StateSprite` subclass of `SKSpriteNode` overriding the `touchesBegan(touches:withEvent)`. And setting `userInteractionEnabled = true`

Comment: That could work generally, but I was more referring to pixel precise taps . You can't do that with overridden touches began if I remember correctly...But maybe this isn't even needed...

Comment: @Whirlwind: For further precision we could detect the touch on the GameScene and then finding the Sprite over that point.

Comment: I think that wouldn't be so precise. Imagine that you have two sprites , one for Nevada and one for California. Look at this [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4rjltr1lqjhpw9m/nevada_california.png?dl=0), and imagine that user taps on California. The green border shows what are the bounds of the Nevada sprite...So as you can see, it overlaps with the California sprite. How would you determine which state should be selected. That is why I have mentioned physics body created from a texture (which will be used with SKPhysicsWorld method - bodyAtPoint:)

Comment: @Whirlwind: You are absolutely right. I totally missed this little aspect: Sprites are rectangular :D

Answer (score 0):

[image]Please refer the link :
https://github.com/ArthurGuibert/FSInteractiveMap

Example 3 in Demo is what you are looking for

Comment: This is certainly a nice library, but it is more UIKit related stuff (FSInteractiveMap is a subclass of UIView). OP tagged SpriteKit in his question.

Comment: @Shemona I agree with Whirwind. Another important thing when you post an answer is to report the relevant code because your link could will become unavailable in future then your answer become unuseful. Good work.